# Video feed flickering/flying in C# using EmguCV

Tags: c#, video-streaming, emgucv

I am creating a program that can dump individual frames from a video feed for a drones competition. I am having a problem where by the wireless video stream coming form the drone is flickering and flying all over the place.

[image: Wireless Video Stream]

I am using this code to capture the video stream:

```
Capture _capture;
Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr,byte> frame;

void StartCamera()
{
    _capture = null;
    _capture = new Capture((int)nudCamera.Value);
    _capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, FrameRate);
    _capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, FrameHeight);
    _capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, FrameWidth);
    webcam_frm_cnt = 0;
    cam = 1;
    Video_seek = 0;
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
}

private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
    try
    {
        Framesno = _capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES);
        frame = _capture.QueryFrame();
        if (frame != null)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = frame.ToBitmap();
            if (cam == 0)
            {
                Video_seek = (int)(Framesno);
                double time_index = _capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC);
                //Time_Label.Text = "Time: " + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(time_index).ToString().Substring(0, 8);
                double framenumber = _capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES);
                //Frame_lbl.Text = "Frame: " + framenumber.ToString();
                Thread.Sleep((int)(1000.0 / FrameRate));
            }
            if (cam == 1)
            {
                //Frame_lbl.Text = "Frame: " + (webcam_frm_cnt++).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Is there a setting somewhere that I am missing?
This video stream flickering seems to happen in other programs too however it fixes itself when you fiddle with the video setting (NTSC/PAL settings)

Edit: So I need to be able to put the video stream into NTSC /M mode, is this possible with EmguCV? If so how do I do it?

Edit 2: All documents that I have read point towards it being completely and utterly impossible to change the video type and that there is no documentation on this topic. I would love to be proved wrong :)

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

This [sourceforge link](http://sourceforge.net/p/emgucv/opencv/ci/895308a8112d226e81646d5136fa9b75b0cdd69b/tree/modules/highgui/src/cap_libv4l.cpp#l869) tells you how to set the video mode.

Comment: Do you know any C# sources? This is just gibberish to me :\